# Converting any Date into MM/DD/YYYY format in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have list of dates like `20/03/2016`, `03/20/2016`, `02/03/20`, `03/jun/18`. In this input format will be `DD/MM/YYYY`, `MM/DD/YYYY`, `DD/MM/YY`, `dd/MMM/YY` formats, but output will only be like `MM/DD/YYYY`, instead of whatever date format is provided.

Comment: It's imposible to do it automatically, how you can decide what you should convert to following date: `01-02-2017`. Accordingly to your post it can be either first of Feb. or second of Jan.

Comment: Yet another example why appropriate datatypes have to be chosen. A date in a (var)char gives nothing but problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DATA  = '03/jun/18'

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), COALESCE(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('/', @DATA)+1, LEN(@DATA))) > 3 THEN @DATA ELSE NULL END,
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@DATA))-1 < 4 THEN @DATA ELSE NULL END, 
            CONVERT(DATETIME, @DATA, CASE WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(@DATA, 4, 2) AS INT) > 12 THEN 101 ELSE 103 END)
         ), 101) [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

**Results :**

@DATA  = '20/03/2016'

```
MM/DD/YYYY
03/20/2016
```

@DATA  = '03/20/2016'

```
MM/DD/YYYY
03/20/2016
```

@DATA  = '02/03/20'

```
MM/DD/YYYY
02/03/2020
```

@DATA  = '03/jun/18'

```
MM/DD/YYYY
06/03/2018
```